# Changing the size of only first letter on a logo

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am trying to make a logo, which contains two words one above each other, and one  big letter in the front of both.

How do I separate the letters, and place them in an order I want , and change the size and color for some only?
Thank you

Comment: I would suggest editing your question to include images so you would get  a better answer

Comment: Hi Matt, I tried

Comment: Apologies..  Im not a mind reader but what are you saying you tried?  You tried to edit you question and failed or you tried to do the work?

Comment: Below:1.You convert the text to outlines, which turns them into individually editable objects. Type > Create Outlines or Shift + Ctrl/Cmd + O. 
2.Then you can either use the Direct Select Tool (A) to select single characters and change their attributes; or you ungroup the words: Object > Ungroup or Shift + Ctrl/Cmd + G) and then select the single characters.

Answer (score 2):

Alternately, you can type the first letter separately, and move it independently.

Answer (score 1):

There is two ways I can think about now:

1. You convert the text to outlines, which turns them into individually editable objects. <kbd>Type > Create Outlines</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>.
2. Then you can either use the `Direct Select Tool` (<kbd>A</kbd>) to select single characters and change their attributes; or you ungroup the words: <kbd>Object > Ungroup</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>) and then select the single characters.

I hope this helps.